# Test SSH connection between remote servers with Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a playbook that creates an SSH key in a remote serverA that then copies it over another remote serverB.

I'm looking for a way to test the SSH connection from serverA to serverB, and then maybe run some command in serverB (for example `uname -a`) to output it as a debug message that confirms the connection is working.

I've been looking around on the Internet and here as well, but I haven't found anything yet...

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick approach would be to :

1. On Ansible's control node, use [openssh_keypair](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/openssh_keypair_module.html) to create an SSH
   keypair. Please pay attention to the path, to make sure the existent
   keypair is not overwritten.
2. Copy the keypair from Ansible's control node to serverA (make sure
   your set the right permssions for the files), use the [copy
   module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html).
3. Copy the public-key (newly generated keypair) from Ansible's control
   node to serverB (make sure your set the right permssions for the
   file), and delete the source keypair.
4. Now, SSH keypairs setup is ready between serverA & serverB.
5. Run [command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html), on the serverA and register it's result e.g:

   `- name: Create variable from command`

   `command: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@serverB 'some_command'`

   `register: command_output`
6. Print out the out the output of the registered result:

`- debug: msg="{{ command_output.stdout }}"`

Comment: Thanks senjoux, it was exactly what I was looking for!
Worked like a charm!!

Comment: Happy to hear that, please the request as resolved ;)